# Given a latitude how many miles is the corresponding longitude?

Tags: circles, spherical-geometry

OK so lines of longitude (the distance/circumference around the earth horizontally) differ based on what latitude you are at (0 at north and south poles up to ~25k at the equator.)

So given a latitude, how can I determine how many miles it would be to go directly east/west around the earth until I was back at the starting point.

If it is easier mathematically to treat the earth like a perfect sphere, then that is fine. I do not need it to be precise, just close enough.

Comment: parallels of latitude are horizontal (a single latitude). Is that what you really wanted? That is, the parallel of latitude $0^\circ$ is $2\pi r$ long?

Comment: @robjohn yeah that sounds right, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parallel of latitude is actually a circle of radius $r\cos(\alpha)$

$\hspace{5cm}$[image]

Thus, the length of the parallel of latitude $\alpha$ is $2\pi r\cos(\alpha)$, where $r$ is the radius of the Earth.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this image: [image]

The north pole is to the right.  Let $\alpha$ represent your latitude, ranging from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians.  Then $\sin\alpha$ represents the radius of the circle you're interested in.  You want to scale this up to earth-size, so multiply everything by $r$, the radius of the earth.  Then, the circle you seek has circumference $2\pi r \sin\alpha$.

Comment: Isn't $\alpha$ in your diagram the co-latitude?

Comment: Yes, but the OP phrased the question in terms of co-latitude (north=0).

Comment: @vadim123 I don't think they did; they said "0 at north and south poles up to ~25k at the equator", so that 0 is not the colatitude but the circumference of the circle at latitude 90.